# Extract specific array from multi dimensional array with index sets

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Suppose inputs are like below.

```
indexSet1 = [0,1,2]
indexSet2 = [1,2]
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Then I want to get a matrix whose height is 3 and width is 2 respectively and elements corresponds to indexSet1's value and indexSet2's one.
In short, I want to a array [[2,3],[4,5],[7,8]] from A by indexSet1 and indexSet2.

When I code like below, I can not get my desire result.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(A)[np.array(indexSet1),np.array(indexSet2)]
array([5, 9])
```

Can anyone know wise methods?
Sorry for my poor English.
And thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]` ?   or `indexSet2 = [0, 1]` ?

Comment: @falsetru Ahh, [[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]] is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
>>> indexSet1 = [0,1,2]
>>> indexSet2 = [1,2]
>>> A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [[A[i][j] for j in indexSet2] for i in indexSet1]
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

In NumPy you can do something like this:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> A[np.array(indexSet1)[:, None], indexSet2]
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```